# Tensorflow dimension size / rank issue on loss function when training

Tags: python, tensorflow, rank, tensor, loss-function

I have a custom loss function which *appears* to be valid (no errors when running those two lines, as below)

`alpha_cost = 2
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.where(tf.less(Y * out, 0), tf.squeeze((alpha_cost*out)**2 - tf.sign(Y)*out + tf.abs(Y)), tf.squeeze(tf.abs(Y - out))))`

However when I actually continue with model training (batch size 10,000), use of this loss function generates the following error ...

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Inputs to operation
>   Select_4 of type Select must have the same size and shape.  Input 0:
>   [1,10000] != input 1: [10000]      [[Node: Select_4 = Select[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Less_7, Squeeze_6, Squeeze_7)]]

Might be a case of just needing to add another tf.squeeze to condense the dimensions... but I've tried a couple and it's not fully cooperating, so perhaps there is a bigger issue with this approach ... thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the numpy module,

```
import numpy as np
```

and defining

```
input0 = tf.where(tf.less(Y * out, 0)
input1 = tf.squeeze((alpha_cost*out)**2 - tf.sign(Y)*out + tf.abs(Y))
```

Try reshaping input1 from a rank-1 array to a row-vector:

```
input1 = np.reshape(input1, (1, 10000))
```

To give it the same shape as input0. You can assert that input1 has the right shape:

```
assert(input1.shape == (1,10000))
```

and check that input0 and input1 have the same dimensions:

```
assert(input0.shape == input1.shape)
```

Comment: Gustav the Great!  Thanks, this approach worked. I ended up using a slight variation, but same line of thought:

input0 = tf.squeeze(tf.less(Y * out, 0))
input1 = tf.squeeze((alpha_cost*out)**2 - tf.sign(Y)*out + tf.abs(Y))
input2 = tf.squeeze(tf.abs(Y - out))
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.where(input0, input1, input2))